# Saving files using writeToFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, writetofile

So I've found a small issue with saving an array using writeToFile to retrieve it later on. I'm using:

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        if ([paths count] > 0)
        {
            NSString *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];

            [finalSavedArray writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayPath forKey:@"SavedArrayPath"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
```

to save 'finalSavedArray' as a file, and later retrieving this array using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"File path: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedArrayPath"]);
        NSMutableArray *savedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedArrayPath"]];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"SAVED ARRAY:%@",savedArray);
        });

    });
```

This works fine when I access the file soon after saving it, but when I restart the app the array comes out as being null and seemingly not found in the saved directory. From a bit of reading it seems that this file directory should be relative as the one that I'm saving to at the moment changes every time you open the app, but I haven't quite been able to figure out how to change my code in order to save it to a relative directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An app's path can change. Never, ever store the absolute path of a file. In your case, just store the path relative to the Documents folder.

When you want to read the file, read the relative path from `NSUserDefaults` and then rebuild the full path just like you do to write the file.

Writing the file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0)
{
    NSString *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];

    [finalSavedArray writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[arrayPath lastPathComponent] forKey:@"SavedArrayPath"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Reading the file:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filename = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedArrayPath"];
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSMutableArray *savedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"SAVED ARRAY:%@",savedArray);
    });

});
```

Comment: So what would I have to change from what I currently have to store the relative path instead of the absolute path?

Comment: See my updated answer. It's just what I said you needed to do.